# Function in Excel to average numbers under weeks column and show them in month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the attached image, I would like to sum the average of every week and show it in months. For example,

weeks no: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Numbers : 12 15 16 5 8 9 45 78 8 96

Show the average of the week in month.

Thanks for help.

Cheers 
Hosein

[image]

Comment: A little bit of Google search should point you in the right direction: [link](https://exceljet.net/formula/average-by-month). Also please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a question - SO is not a free coding service and we expect the user to show some effort (i.e. formula/code that you have tried) before assisting.

Comment: @Davesexcel that's what I learned from SO - the user needs to show that s/he made some effort in finding the correct answer, will show us what s/he tried so far and where s/he got stuck, or maybe s/he doesn't understand a given solution and we will help with the clarification. TBH it took me 30 seconds to find the google link which makes me believe that the user is simply looking for a free solution, without trying to learn Excel/VBA by himself. I'm very happy to help but - as [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) suggests, the user needs to "Search, and research" first.

Comment: @JustynaMK Thanks for the answer. It was my first time to use Stackoverflow. I have tried before what you have mentioned, and it didnt solve my problem. But, you are right, I should have mentioned it that I tried that formula and didnt get answer.

Comment: No worries @Hosein Neizan, glad that you clarified it. `AVERAGEIFS` should give you the correct answer, unless I misunderstood your request. I'll post an answer for your analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The following formula will give you the average for each month for a given row:

```
=AVERAGEIFS($A$4:$V$4,$A$1:$V$1,">="&A9,$A$1:$V$1,"<="&EOMONTH(A9,0))
```

Here's the final result:

[image]

I'm hoping it's a good starting point.